# Name/Solution of this Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation of the form

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \omega \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

Where $\omega$ is a constant

I was wondering what kind of solutions this differential equation has. Just by guessing, I can tell the solution has to be some sort of exponential.

Any references for further study would be welcome too.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a linear (time) homogeneous second-order ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients, whose solution (if I recall correctly) is attributed to Euler.

More generally, you have the differential equation $$ A \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + B \frac{dy}{dx} + C = f(x)$$ where if $f(x)=0$ (as it is in your case), the differential equation is homogeneous. Then the general solution has the form $$C_1e^{\omega_1x} + C_2e^{\omega_2x}$$ where $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are the roots of the so-called characteristic equation $Az^2 + Bz+ C = 0$

(Essentially, to check that this is true, you plug in $y=C_1e^{\omega_1x}$ and find that it solves the equation, then do it again for $y=C_2e^{\omega_2x}$. Then there is an idea called the superposition principle that says the sum of these two solutions is also a solution, and there are further results from the theory of ODEs which asserts that all solutions to this ODE must take this form.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a general example of a harmonic oscillator. You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) for more information.

They're used in physics for things like springs and simplified pendulums. More generally, they describe systems with periodic behavior.

As mentioned by the other answers the solution is some linear combination of exponential factors. Because the equation is linear, you could solve by equating coefficients and summing various solutions.  Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) for more information. I personally use the Laplace transform to solve these, but there many other methods to solve the harmonic differential equation.

Comment: This isn't really a harmonic oscillator, given that $k=0$, hence no oscillation.

Comment: @AlexR. So it's a limiting example, it really makes no difference on what it is, namely a harmonic oscillator with $k=0$. I'm just citing the definition.

Comment: You could say it's degenerate, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonably simple to solve using the substitution $u=\frac{dy}{dx}$. You wind up with the first-order equation $\frac{du}{dx}+\omega u=0$ which has the solution $u=Ae^{-\omega x}$, and then turn that into $\frac{dy}{dx}=Ae^{-\omega x}$ and integrate to get $y=-\frac{A}{\omega}e^{-\omega x} + C$, or by substituting $A = -\omega B$ you have $y = Be^{-\omega x} + C$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a "linear homogeneous second order differential equation with constant coefficients".  The solutions to such (they are generally the first higher order equation studied in an introductory differential equations course.)  The solution is **related** to the exponential.  In fact, by replacing $y$ with $e^{rx}$ you get the "characteristic equation", a polynomial equation whose roots will guide you to the general solution to the differential equation.